Finding Appropriate Formulas/Methods for Finding Correlation.
I want to find the correlation between birth rate (per 1000 people) and unemployment rate in a country from 2000 to 2022 and give suggestions for solving the birth rate declining problem. I know this is a very complicated question as it involve many others factors but let's just simplify the situation for now.
The current method I use is Pearson correlation. I took birth rate and unemployment rate in Malaysia from 2000 to 2022, I got -0.357 (I used excel for calculation). However, when I compared among others countries (I took birth rate and unemployment rate in 2018 for another 36 developing countries), I got 0.23. This makes me confuse that whether there is correlation between birth rate and unemployment rate or not. It also makes me concern that my methods are wrong.
My question is that can I use Pearson correlation for this situation since the data I use are somewhat time series? If not, which method should I use? If yes, how do you make conclusion from that conflicting results.

If you're used to hard sciences like chemistry or physics, social statistics tend to have notoriously low $r$ values.  It's completely plausible that some countries have positive correlations while others have negative correlations.
